# Is there a good (and simple) open source mail client for windows?

Tags: email, language-agnostic, open-source

I'm looking for a simple open source mail client to personalize, something really simple but that has all the basic features like downloading email, sending replying and attaching files.

Does something like this even exists? If not are there libraries to use?

Language is not a problem.

Thank you

Comment: What language would be preferred?

Comment: Super Users personalize a mail client by modifing the source code and recompiling it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I love [Thunderbird](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/thunderbird/), but I'll admit it was a bit of an uncomfortable transition from Outlook. Still, once I got comfortable with it, I haven't looked back.

There's a link on the right to download the source if you're wanting to tinker.

Comment: Have you ever worked with thunderbird code? I fear is a gargantuan monster to play with..

Comment: It's a pretty mature Mozilla project, so I expect you are right. I've never messed with the source, myself.

Answer (score 2):

You can always go for mutt with cygwin. :) Its simple in that it is very basic (no GUI), but definitely not simple to use. Still, its a good client.